# How can i localize the Liferay blog post date display?

Tags: localization, internationalization, liferay, blogs, portlet

We use Liferay with German as the default user's settings, as described here:

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Configure+time+zones+and+locale

However, as soon as we use the blog portlet, the date of a blog entry is displayed in English format: 7/11/12 6:00 AM

Is there a way to change the default display to German format?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cann't emulate this problem, if I switch to German (de) then the date is diplayed in german format, see screenshots:

German:
[image]

English:
[image]

and if I switch user default language to german, then I get german date format too:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, then I have to check better, if my user default language setting is active at all